# npm install error Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.12 install script

Tags: npm

I am getting this error when am trying to do npm install...am struck with this nearly for 4 days...please can someone help me out...

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n pm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" 
npm ERR! node v0.10.33  
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.5  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  
npm ERR! errno ENOENT  
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.12 install: `node install.js`  
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT  
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.12 install script.  
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,  
npm ERR! not with npm itself.  
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
npm ERR!     node install.js  
npm ERR! You can get their info via:  
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: I'm not sure if helps, but here I was with ENOENT issue because lacks of bzip and tar utils.

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue on Windows. To fix it, I took the following steps:

1. Install the latest version of phantomjs (currently, phantomjs-1.9.8-windows) locally, by downloading and unziping. I had a previous version which was not compatible with phantomjs npm package.
2. Update your environment variable to point to latest version of phantomjs.exe (`PHANTOMJS_HOME`).
3. Exit and restart windows prompt or shell to recognize variable.
4. Now, `npm install` or specifically, `npm install phantomjs@1.9.12` should work correctly.

You can test your local phantomjs executable install with a `where phantomjs` and `phantomjs -v` from a git bash shell or command prompt.

Comment: Gary's proposed solution is a good one.  I believe you are seeing the problem because you don't have `python` and `Visual Studio` installed.  Those are necessary to build the phantom binary addon yourself.

If you download the pre-built binary, you won't have to install them.

Answer (score 1):

I am working under a corporate proxy, So it was blocking npm to download 'phantom' from https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip

So, I fixed it in the following way...

1. Download 'phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip' file from the above link directly.
2. Copy and paste it to 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip'
3. Now, just do 'npm install', it will work like a charm.

Comment: I was coping with this problem quite a while in a similar environment. This post solved the problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the error and find the correct version of phantomjs (might be 1.9.12 or 2.1.1 ).
2. Find the appropriate file in the [maven repo](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/klieber/phantomjs/1.9.8/).
3. Download the zip file and copy the same zip file to `C:\Users\User_ID\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\` and paste it (in zip format).
4. Set or create an environment variable  `PHANTOMJS_HOME`
   to `C:\Users\User_ID\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-1.9.8-windows.zip`.
5. restart the command prompt and run `npm i` or `npm install`