# Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install script 'node install.js'

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I am trying to install phantomjs on a windows 7 machine and am getting this error .

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodist\\v\\nodev5.5.0\\node.exe"   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodist\\bin\\node_mod  
ules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"  
npm ERR! node v5.5.0  
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  

npm ERR! phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install: `node install.js`  
npm ERR! Exit status 1  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 install script 'node   install.js'.  
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
```

There are many issues logged  in the phantomjs github repo for the same  or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645207/npm-install-error-failed-at-the-phantomjs1-9-12-install-script) SO questionbut none of it is helping in my case.

This is what is the state of my machine

- I have phantomjs installed locally at **C:\npm\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe** but when I run the npm install,it will always try to install by downloading which is where the problem for me.My corporate proxy is blocking the direct downloads .I also cannot use the  `--phantomjs_cdnurl` switch mentioned here https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs#deciding-where-to-get-phantomjs
- I can run the command and it works fine
      `phantomjs -v

       2.1.1`

But when I run `npm install` on my project it is trying to install the phantomjs and will run into the above error.Another thing I observed from the npm log

`Considering PhantomJS found at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodist\bin\phantomjs.CMD
Found PhantomJS at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodist\bin\phantomjs.CMD ...verifying
Error verifying phantomjs, continuing { [Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodist\bin\phantomjs.CMD --version`

it is trying to run the phantomjs.CMD --version which also failing

```
Error verifying phantomjs, continuing { [Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodist\bin\phantomjs.CMD --versio
n
internal/child_process.js:274
  var err = this._handle.spawn(options);
                         ^

TypeError: Bad argument
    at TypeError (native)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:274:26)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodist\bin\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\bin\phantomjs:22:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodist\\bin\\phantomjs.CMD --version' }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As a temporary work around I am able to get it installed by using --ignore-scripts

`npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 --ignore-scripts`

I also logged an issue in the github repo for the same

https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/649

### edited

This issue was part of the build process script I was using and it does a npm clean and install everytime with a bunch of other things .So this issue appears many times in the same machine where we automated tests using phantomjs. I got some time to look into this issue and it seems my corporate proxy is blocking the download from https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip. I knew this before and had manually installed phantomjs binary and added to system path but the npm install still trying to download locally as showing in the log below.

```
Considering PhantomJS found at C:\npm\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.EXE
Looks like an `npm install -g` on windows; skipping installed version.
```

My corporate proxy was blocking all the phantomjs CDN urls as well (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs)

The work around I used was to get the **phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip** and copy it to the  **C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip** and that resolved the issue with the build script.If someone cleans the temp directory,issue will come back. Even this is a work around but the corporate proxy cannot be unblocked for obvious reasons :)

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: thanks, using --ignore-scripts worked for me, when none of the other offered solutions did :)

Comment: `--ignore-scripts` even works in Jenkins nodejs tool configuration (global npm packages to install).  Without this setting, Jenkins was reinstalling the packages every time, likely due to the errors.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes when we try to install phantomjs locally, it will work. But for global, I suggest you to type

```
sudo npm install -g phantomjs-prebuilt --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across same error , It will solved by following changes, Hope it will help you .

```
sudo npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.13 --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove any vpn connected in your system. I removed office vpn and then hit `npm install` it worked fine for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

All those solutions didn't help me

--ignore-scripts helped but finally installed phantomjs is unworkable and my karma tests were not able to use phantomjs browser.

However I found solution for my Win machine. I downloaded distribute with .exe file from `https://phantomjs.org/download.html` and then unpacked locally (it can be any folder):

then added to:
`set Path=;C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin;$Path`

After that 'npm install' was able to re-use it:

```
 [exec] > node install.js

 [exec] 

 [exec] Considering PhantomJS found at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.EXE

 [exec] Found PhantomJS at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.EXE ...verifying

 [exec] Writing location.js file

 [exec] PhantomJS is already installed on PATH at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.EXE

 [exec] 

 [exec] > phantomjs@2.1.7 install C:\xxx\client\ui\src\main\web\build\node_modules\phantomjs
 [exec] > node install.js
```